# Azure WebApp with Azure AD App returning `auth/login/aad/callback` permission

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

After setting up a Azure Web App with Azure AD Authentication, the site is returning a `401` after authenticating.

This is the auth flow as I see it.

1. Go to `https://mysite-$environment.azurewebsites.net/`
2. Redirects to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/`
3. Authenticate using my credentials
4. Redirects to `https://mysite-$environment.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`
5. Error `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` HttpStatus `401`.

**Long version**

I have 3 x Web Apps in Azure under the same Service Plan - 1 x website and 2 x APIs.

I would like these to use Azure AD for authentication.

So, I created an Azure AD App using Powershell.

```
$app = @{
    DisplayName = "azad-$environment-mysite"
    IdentifierUris = @(
        "https://mysite-$environment.azurewebsites.net",
        "https://mysite-api-$environment.azurewebsites.net",
        "https://mysite-api-2-$environment.azurewebsites.net"
    )
    HomePage = "https://mysite-$environment.azurewebsites.net"
    ReplyUrls = @(
        "https://mysite-$environment.azurewebsites.net",
        "https://mysite-api-$environment.azurewebsites.net",
        "https://mysite-api-2-$environment.azurewebsites.net"
    )
    AvailableToOtherTenants = $false
}

New-AzureRmADApplication @app
```

Then using the `ApplicationId` returned, I have setup the Azure AD through the portal `Web App > Authentication / Authorization` blade.

This is similar scenario to question asked over at [Azure AD server authentication, No permission to view directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38874352/azure-ad-server-authentication-no-permission-to-view-directory) question.

Comment: Are you using aspnet? Mvc Web API ?

Comment: @Thomas. Sorry, I forgot that detail. I'm using ASP.NET Core / MVC6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549414/5349104 Read this answer to get a complete understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register each app in the AAD and you can do it, more easily, via azure-portal.

When you have the web-app registered through the "Express" process everything should work as expected (OAuth2 flow). The problem may come with your API-app especially if you need to access with server-to-server.

Because the process is a little bit long to write here I wrote two posts:

[Web API access through Azure Active Directory](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.ar/2017/04/web-api-access-through-azure-active.html)

[API-APP server-to-server through Azure Active Directory](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com.ar/2017/04/api-app-server-to-server-through-azure.html)

In the first post you can see the REST flow using POSTMAN.